# Finding all paths in networkx

Tags: graph, networkx

I am looking for an all (longest) paths finding algorithm to be used in a `networkx multidigraph`. All, I can find is the `all_simple_paths`, algorithm, which requires me to give the source node and target node.

One crude way that comes to my mind is to traverse all nodes using the `all_simple_paths` function. But I am looking for a more effficient implementation, if anything of such sort is available

Is there any other implementation that is available in networks. I am new to networkx, so please fogive if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Looks like an NP-hard problem, even for non-digraphs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: Even better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ww0gwEszo about longest paths...